# Did "Peacekeeper Wars" Let "Farscape" Finish Properly?

Tags: farscape

I know *Farscape* was cancelled, without notice, and ended in a cliffhanger.  When that happened, I remember reading that the production company decided to try to resolve it with *The Peacekeeper Wars* and started production on that even without a buyer (and it was eventually aired on SciFi).

Did this bring the series to a satisfying conclusion?

(I've always wanted to watch the entire series, after seeing a few of the early episodes, but didn't want to read about or see what happened in the end because that would spoil it for me.  I just want to know if it ends in a way that makes it feel complete.  There's so many shows to watch now I don't want to get wrapped up in it if I'm only going to be frustrated by the end of the story.)

---

**IMPORTANT**
Please remember to use spoiler markdown if you're including spoilers like @Izkata did in his answer -- remember, I have not seen more than a few episodes!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While this answer is entirely subjective, I definitely felt that the series had reached a conclusion. As I remember, there weren't any major loose threads that never got wrapped up.

That being said, it did feel a bit rushed. Which, considering they were trying to cover the major plot points for a season in a couple made-for-tv movies, is probably an entirely reasonable feeling.

So for what its worth, I say feel free to watch the series and the movie and you won't feel like you've been abandoned in the dark.

Comment: And if you can't get enough of Farscape (and who can really) they did another season (like Buffy) in comic book form. It picks up right at the last scene in the PKW mini-series. It's plotted out by series creator Rockne O'Bannon and released by BOOM! Studios.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add that the Peacekeeper Wars miniseries not only satisfactorily winds up the series (albeit much more compressed than fans would've liked), it is also a satisfactory and exciting story to watch -- unlike, say, the Babylon 5 made-for-TV movies, which were progressively more disappointing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The Peacekeeper Wars was a much-condensed 5th season, so a number of things that were supposed to be introduced over time were introduced in a few minutes:

> Such as the ability of Chiana's new eyes: After going blind due to her old ability, a Diagnosian managed to give her transplants.  These new eyes let her see energy, even through walls and other obstacles.

Plot-wise, without giving up toooo many spoilers (For others, I suppose - I see you've not seen the series yet, either..):

> The Season 4 cliffhanger is temporary (Of course!  How can you keep the series going without them?).  Crichton makes it back to earth (mostly).  The Scarran threat is dealt with, as are the Peacekeepers.

Comment: Thank you for using the spoiler markdown -- you're right.  I have not seen anymore than a few episodes!

Comment: @TangoOversway I almost missed the point that you'd not seen the series.  After posting the answer, I reread the question and had to go back and edit more of it into the spoilers...

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't seen much of the series, I'll keep things general.  Farscape does season finale cliffhangers in a big way.  So, the end of the 4th season has a big cliffhanger, which fans at the time had no resolution to.  The Peacekeeper Wars provides resolution for this cliffhanger, and tells a heavily compressed version of what would presumably have been season 5's story.  This suffers in quality much the same way as the *Firefly* film *Serenity* does; too much story in too little time means the quality is lower.  But it tells a satisfactory resolution of the season 4 cliffhanger, and has our intrepid heroes go on one last adventure, which doesn't end in a cliffhanger.  They get a suitable 'ride off into the sunset' sort of ending.  If you're a comic book reader, you can see the story continue after the ending of the Peacekeeper Wars by picking up the Farscape comics.

Answer (score 1):

I was very satisfied with Peacekeeper Wars.  Incidentally PK Wars only came about because of the MASSIVE fan outcry after the lame cliff-hanger "oh sorry we're canceling the show" ending.  You can read about it on the SyFy Channel's website. But give the fanboys a big high-5 for a job well done - I think it was on the order of 100,000 emails! Fans LOVED that show. In fact, there was even a [sic] "Bring Back Farscape" website were the fans organized their campaign!  I know because I joined. :D

And yes likewise, SERENITY also came about because Joss Whedon got something like 40,000 emails from fans upset about the canceling of Firefly, a show which Joss personally loved, so Joss used all those emails as leverage to BEG the studios to let him make SERENITY to "finish" the story.